# D3 renders SVG. How can I get that SVG programmatically?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, zombie.js

I have a page that runs javascript on load that renders a map in SVG using d3. I want to automatically get a copy of that HTML + SVG. I can't just curl the the server -- that just returns the HTML of the page before the javascript runs. I guess I could use selenium or zombiejs -- but is there an easier way?

Comment: Is getting the `innerHTML` of the `<body>` tag through plain old Javascript not an option?

Comment: @juan.facorro I'd need a way to write it to a file. I don't think js can write to files (For security reasons).

Comment: You can probably render it with node.js, which would allow you to save to a file. Since node.js is not a browser, you need something that "speaks DOM". [JSDOM with d3](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/JyldAkWkTvI) is the simple option, but probably has limitations, like if you need to measure stuff from the DOM. If that's the case then you have to use phontomjs (which zombiejs is built on top of).

Comment: When you say you _have_ a page, does it mean that you have access to the page code and data or is the page hosted on an external web-server which you want to scrap?

Comment: @musically_ut both -- I am rendering a page w/ d3. I want to optimize by saving the step of building the map. I want to automate the process of copying and pasting the SVG.

Comment: What do you get if you just call the svg on-complete like - var shouldbeallyousvg = d3.selectAll("svg"); Couldn't you do it in 2 part, I would imagine the html you are generating is probably simple enough to post or curl etc.

Comment: @Dylan you mean have the JS post the SVG back to the server and then collect it there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had to do something very similar lately. Here are few things we tried:

- Using jsdom
- Use phantomjs to visit the page and grab output
- Rewrite using some server side language + data format
- Don't manipulate DOM at all

### JSDOM

Ya, it supports SVG, but NOT SVG 1.1. Which means the text element doesn't work among other things. It may eventually have this support though.

### PhantomJS

This worked but it is potentially slow. The only way you can tell if the SVG is done rendering is by adding a class or element to the page and have phantom wait for that object to appear. Once it does grab the svg element using standard DOM operations. For about 1k objects on screen after a few ajax calls this took maybe 5 seconds. 6k objects, it took around a minute.

### Rewrite on the server side

Ultimately, we had to do this since we had a LOT of objects on screen. We had some data model that we took and mimic'd the output. This is faster since it's string based and doesn't require a bunch of DOM look ups/writes and not spinning up a leaky browser is also a plus. The down side is that you'll have 2 implementations of the same code.

### Don't use D3 or Raphael

If you are able to write SVG using strings/templates then you can use the same JS on the client and server side. This by far seems like the best approach in retrospect. If I was able to go back I'd have acted more disgruntled towards the fact that we were using Raphael and just pushed hard on using handlebars, backbone, rendr and a node server.

Comment: Just to add, there is a write up I found in the past to be helpful in regard to server side rendering of d3 http://mango-is.com/blog/engineering/pre-render-d3-js-charts-at-server-side.html

Comment: @ChristopherHackett I added some detail as to why JSDom didn't work for us. I couldn't quite remember until I read that article. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can render the svg by running d3 server side via nodejs (as @meetamit hinted towards) and then serialize it to a file.

Here is a guide to do it: [Creating an SVG file with D3 and Node.js](http://robballou.com/2013/creating-an-svg-file-with-d3-and-node-js/)

Comment: I'm going to try this. Have you tested it with the text element or any SVG 1.1 features?

Comment: @Parris I haven't tried it myself, but looking at [nodejs's xmldom project](https://github.com/jindw/xmldom) it's compatible with W3C DOM level2 and some of level 3. I'm unsure whether this envelopes SVG 1.1 (probably not). But it may just automagically work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you'd have to render the Javascript at some point, which CURL cannot do. I would try looking into something like http://phantomjs.org/